# How do I redirect a subset of files in a folder to a different folder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I recently took over managing a WordPress site for work, and have done some clean-up. One thing I did was re-locate some important files into a specific folders to better facilitate maintenance of file revisions. I updated all internal links to the new path.

Unfortunately, we have users who have bookmarked the old locations, and they are getting a 404 when attempting to re-download the files. The scale of this is significant, and I need to find a way to point the old links to the new ones.

The problems:

1. The old folders still contain files that are being served to other portions of the site, so I can't redirect the entire folder.
2. There are hundreds of files.
3. There were about 3 folders holding the files for 14 different products (not unique from>to locations).

Here are some examples:

**OLD:**

- /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/HR59-K-F-D.dwg
- /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/HR59-K-F-D.dwg
- /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/HR59-A-F-D.step
- /wp-content/uploads/2019/01/L-A-A-B.igs
- /wp-content/uploads/2019/01/L-A-B-B.sldprt
- /wp-content/uploads/2019/01/M-A-C-B.x_t
- /wp-content/uploads/2019/01/M-A-C-B.dxf

**NEW:**

- /uploads/3Dmodels/Product1/HR59-K-F-D.dwg
- /uploads/3Dmodels/Product1/HR59-A-F-D.step
- /uploads/3Dmodels/Product2/L-A-A-B.igs
- /uploads/3Dmodels/Product2/L-A-B-B.sldprt
- /uploads/3Dmodels/Product3/M-A-C-B.igs
- /uploads/3Dmodels/Product3/M-A-C-B.dxf

**What I am looking for:**
A way to look for a subset (based on start of filename) of a specific folder, and only redirect/rewrite that to a new folder. That is, the unique thing about the files is the start of the filename when located in 1 specific folder. For example:

EXAMPLE 1:

```
For files in: /wp-content/uploads/2016/08/
That start with: HR59-
Redirect to: /uploads/3Dmodels/Product1/
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
For files in: /wp-content/uploads/2019/01/
That start with: L-
Redirect to: /uploads/3Dmodels/Product2/
```

EXAMPLE 3:

```
For files in: /wp-content/uploads/2019/01/
That start with: M-
Redirect to: /uploads/3Dmodels/Product3/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just check for the appropriate pattern with [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2016/08/(HR59-[^/]+)$ /uploads/3Dmodels/Product1/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2019/01/(L-[^/]+)$ /uploads/3Dmodels/Product2/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2019/01/(M-[^/]+)$ /uploads/3Dmodels/Product3/$1 [R,L]
```

When everything works as expected, you may replace `R,L` with `R=301,L`, but not while [testing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)

Comment: @Marco You tagged the question [tag:mod-rewrite], but `RedirectMatch` works just as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a reason for choosing rewrite rather than redirect? I'd like customers to see the new path. I'm thinking of using: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/(L-[^/]+)$ /uploads/3Dmodels/Product1/$1`

Comment: I misunderstood your comment, `RewriteRule` can be used for both rewrite or redirect. It depends on the flag `R`.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! I just realized that there was a change in filenames as well, so `/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/HR59-K-F-D.dwg` should actually now be `/uploads/3Dmodels/Product1/HD59-K-F-D.dwg` (note the change from 'R' to 'D' in filename). How can I look for 'HR59-' but replace with 'HD59-' in the redirect rather than passing the same filename?

Comment: I figured it out: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/HR59-([^/]+)$ /uploads/3Dmodels/Product1/HD59-$1`